# Как сделать засветление под конец блока

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что мне надо. Конструкция

```
<div>
  <div class = 'header'>My header</div>
  <div class = 'information'> bla bla</div>
</div>
```

И надо чтобы часть `bla bla` засветилась.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```css
.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, white, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0));
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя
    Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х
    годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```